# Finding the solution $x = \arg \max f(x)=\frac{e^{-2x^{0.7}}}{10^{3.5e^{-x/3.5}}} $

Tags: calculus, optimization

I want to find an $x>0$ corresponding to the maximum value of the function : 
$$f(x) = \frac{e^{-2x^{0.7}}}{10^{3.5e^{-x/3.5}}}$$

My way is to first express $g(x)=\log_{10}f(x)$ (or any monotonic functions like $\ln f(x)$) and then the answer will be the solution of the equation $g'(x)=0$, where $g'(x)$ is the derivative of the function $g(x)$. Simulation seems good. May I know if it is theoretically sound for this approach?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please don't use * for multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is positive, maximizing it is equivalent to maximizing its logarithm (since the logarithm is strictly increasing). In order for you to have a maximizer, you need $(\log f)'$ to change from being positive to negative (first derivative test) or you can use the second derivative test as well on $\log f$.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about a global maximum not just local maxima.

Comment: yes, I mean a global maximum.